# Rails: Trix editor showing image and image size when caption is not specified

Tags: ruby-on-rails, trix, actiontext

I am working on a **Rails** 6 application with Ubuntu 18.

I just installed **ActionText** for the Trix Editor (what you see is what you get), so that I can save text to the database which can be modified by an admin, however, when I add an **image** using the **Trix Editor** if I don't specify a caption for the image, it shows the **name** and **size** of the **image** as the **caption**

I just want to remove the captions, and only have the captions when I specify them myself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I later figured out how to do it.

After successfully installing ActionText:

```
rails action_text:install
```

And successfully setting it up:

```
// application.js
require("trix")
require("@rails/actiontext")

// actiontext.scss
@import "trix/dist/trix";
```

Modify these lines of code in `app/views/active_storage/blobs/_blob.html.erb` from this:

```
<span class="attachment__name"><%= blob.filename %></span>
<span class="attachment__size"><%= number_to_human_size blob.byte_size %></span>
```

to this

```
<span class="attachment__name"><% blob.filename %></span>
<span class="attachment__size"><% number_to_human_size blob.byte_size %></span>
```

That is, remove the `=` sign from the both lines of code, so that the **name** and **size** of the image is not displayed as the caption when a caption is not specified.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Comment: Removing the `=` will still render the spans.  You can delete all the lines, even the `else` statement

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the view `app/views/active_storage/blobs/_blob.html.erb` where you'll find an `if` statement.

```rb
<% if caption = blob.try(:caption) %>
    <%= caption %>
<% else %>
    <span class="attachment__name"><%= blob.filename %></span>
    <span class="attachment__size"><%= number_to_human_size blob.byte_size %></span>
<% end %>
```

Get rid of the `else` part or update the content in a way that shows whatever you want.

Removing the `=` does not print the result, but still calculates it internally.